# Visual Studio and an Access Database - Operation must use an updateable query

Tags: visual-studio, ms-access

I am deploying an .accdb file to the same directory as my windows forms program is being installed.  However when attempting to update data in the database i get a "Operation must use an updateable query" error.

The file attributes are not read only, however when I open the accdb file it stats that the database has been opened read only.  I must save a copy to make it not read only.

I do not believe this has anything to do with permissions, or file attributes.  This is only on Vista, XP appears to work ok.  The original accdb file is not read only when i open it.

What is visual studio doing to the accdb file to make it read only? and how can i fix it.

Comment: How are you accessing data, using ADO.Net?  Does it work when you run from the debugger but not when installed?  I'm not clear why you think it is Visual Studio's fault, rather than Windows or the .Net framework.  Also, it might help if you could provide some code...

Comment: I am varily confident that the code has nothing to do with it as when i open up hte accdb file by itself from the installled directory, that is when it states that the database has been opened read only.  i must save a copy to make it not read only.  you are correct in that it might not be VS fault.  it could indeed be windows or the .net framework.  mostly i am trying to find a solution to the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Are you installing into the Program Files heierarchy? If so that's read only for users and would cause the Access database to be read only.  You should be installed any Access database file to the users Application Data folder.

Comment: i have attempted to do that, but can not.  I can get the install to install the accdb file to the ProgramData directory, but it is still exhibiting the readonly behavior.  how do i install to the users application data folder and then how do i path the connection string in the app.config file/settings?  thank you for your time.

Comment: Program Data might also be read only for the users.  I can't recall right now.      Regretfully I don't know anything about how the Visual Studio installer works so I can't help with that part of things.  As far as the app.config file settings in the Access world we would install the Access databaes iles into a standard sub folder of the Application Data folder such as \%appdata%\My wonderful app folder\  Then the program would default to look into that folder.  If not found then it would ask the user where the Access database file resided.

Comment: So if I were to install into the users application Data Folder: ie 'C:\Users\Voyagr12\AppData\Local\my program\' the connection string in the app.config file would be:
Data Source=\%appdata%\my program;

Comment: That's the idea.  However I hav eno idea if your programming environment will suppoer %appdata% in the app.config file.    Or even indeed that's even necessary.  Maybe you can just use that location in your program using some kind of system call/variable and not even using the app.config file.

Comment: okay, well, I guess I will see what I can come up with.  THanks for your help.